# Bootstrap colums for small width only?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to create columns in Bootstrap for a small width ONLY?

The default colums are inherited for larger sizes. So a 2 colum layout for for the xs width would also be a 2 colum layout for sm, md, etc.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `"small width ONLY"` means that other screen sizes should display like a block, the rendering will be like a 1 column layout. So simply add a layout rule for SM to append it to all `>=SM` screen sizes.

For example, if you want a 2 column layout for XS only and 1 column layout for all other screen sizes, this should do the trick :

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```